# Can the default configurations be changed in Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Is there any way to change the default values for database vCPUs and WebServer vCPUs while or after creating the Composer configuration?

Please refer to this link. https://cloud.google.com/composer/pricing#environment_sizing

[Cloud Composer Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFVxm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not. As described in the documentation, it's not adjustable. In fact, all this element doesn't appear in your console because there are managed on Google Side and you can't have access to it.

This machine types have been designed by Google to commit SLA on Composer.

A such huge power is often useless for dev/uat environment and it's money consuming for nothing.
The workaround that we found in my company is to set up a mutualized Composer for all no prod project. Not ideal but financially interesting.

At the opposite, if you are a very big user of Composer and the current power is too low, open a case to the support, it maybe could increase your machine power

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Interesting idea about the collective non-prod environments. Might be worth a try.